# Saving Ai files as editable pdf?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo, pdf, file-format

Sounds simple, but it's giving me a headache, I'm able to save the file and open it in Adobe acrobat pro dc, and edit the text but my client is asking for the logo symbol, to still be editable for them. Adobe acrobat shows it as a picture above the editable text, but now it won't allow a simple color change to the part of the picture he want's editable. Is there a way to keep the photo editable, since my client doesn't have illustrator?

Answer (score 1):

if your client doesn't have Acrobat Pro version (only Acrobat Reader) then they won't be able to edit it--there are some free PDF editors available for download (but I have never used one since I have Pro) and IF your client doesn't have the used fonts loaded on their machine, they will have problems with text reflow possibly--FYI the intent of an editable PDF from illustrator is that is be editable in Illustrator--also if they get Acrobat Pro they would probably need a plug-in like Pitstop Pro ($800) to make any edits and they would need other Adobe apps to edit it properly--I think the best thin to do is volunteer to make the edits for your client

Answer (score 1):

"Saving as editable PDF" in Illustrator means that Illustrator embeds the ai file when it creates the PDF, so that it can reuse it. This does, of course, bloat the PDF… and it requires Illustrator for editing.

Acrobat does not have the capability to edit vector graphics; it does need a helper for that (such as Illustrator). Acrobat DC is quite good with text (much better than older versions), and has some raster image modification capabilities.

A workaround in your situation, if your client has Reader XI or newer, would be creating a Button field where the logo is placed, and import the logo as icon of that field. It is possible to use the importIcon() JavaScript method to import an icon into the Button field (however, if Reader is used, the icon to be imported must be a PDF). So, your client can change the logo; for creating or editing the logo, your client would have to have according software.